# How can I show related columns in a table in PHP Filament v3

Tags: php, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I have two tables Advisors and AdvisorRegions and the relation looks like this.
One advisorRegion has many advisors and one advisor has one advisorRegion.

Now I want to show the name of the advisorRegion in the advisors-resource table.

I have the advisors_region_id as an foreign key in my advisor table

How do i do this in filament php v3.

I tried to look it up but found nothng interesting at all.

Comment: "I tried to look it up but found nothng interesting at all." - really? you should start from what you tried to do, and post any code in the question that may help people help you.  read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Displaying data from relationships](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/tables/columns/relationships#displaying-data-from-relationships) section of the docs:

```
TextColumn::make('advisorsRegion.name');
```

Where `advisorsRegion` is the name of the relationship in your model