Filament, records listing, running a closure on the value?
I have a listing setup:
public static function table(Table $table): Table
{
    return $table
        ->columns([
            Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('column1'),
            Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('column2'),
            Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('column3'),
            Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('column4'),
            Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('column5')
       ]);
}

lets say, "column3" is only a number, pointing to an array (as key) and I would like to render its value, not the number itself.
But the same question may go, if it were a PK key.
How to?

similar like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76942865/how-can-i-show-related-columns-in-a-table-in-php-filament-v3

I figured it out:
https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/tables/columns/custom
a view template was needed for this
